# GCM Cordova - Tap not opening app

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM Cordova (downloaded yesterday with Cordova 2.6) I find that whilst I've got notifications to be received successfully, using the example code.  However tapping on the notification just clears it and closes the notification list - doesn't launch the app itself.

Running the app on the phone connected to Eclipse shows me that the GCMIntentService receives the message (onMessage) and finally runs a 'Releasing wakelock' but the app doesn't open.  Shouldn't it, or do I have to change the code from the example to achieve this.

I've also noticed that if I force stop the app, notifications are no longer received.  Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the answer is not simple - but involves setting up an intent.

I followed this article to start:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/android-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html

The tap doesn't work at this point, so I did the following.  Added the following code to the Manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="NAMEOFAPP.STARTME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

This code was placed into the GCMIntentService.java file - it replaces much of the notification code that the project above refers to:

```
    String message = extras.getString("message");
    String title = extras.getString("title");

    Intent nintent = new Intent("uk.ac.chester.uocmobile.STARTME");
    nintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


    nintent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, nintent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentIntent(pintent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
```

You'll need to add this import to the same file:

```
            import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

If you do this without the following process you'll get an error on compilation.

Right click your project, and go to Android Tools -> Add Support Library.  Add the Android Support Library, revision 13.  This adds those calls to your project and makes it all work.

When you tap on a notification after this, it will open your app - sending you to the homepage you've set.  This may not be ideal, but works for me.  I've added an onstart and onresume to make sure that the app (in HTML/JS) on either iOS or Android will check for new messages in the same way as the FaceBook app works.